# I'm trying to create a Python miner, can I get some guidance please?

Tags: cryptonight, mining-theory, monero-hash

I have been wondering how to make a Python Monero miner. I know about [py-cryptonight](https://github.com/ph4r05/py-cryptonight), but does anyone know anything about how to actually code with it? I understand that `cn_slow_hash` is for mining, but when I try to create a hash, I get a bunch of random characters. I know that Python miners are slow, but this is just an experiment. I know how to code in Python fairly well, but not great. Can someone please guide me along? Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to edit and re-tag my post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general steps are as follows:

1. Call your Monero daemon's RPC method [get_block_template](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block_template).
2. Take the `blockhashing_blob` from the response and convert the hex to binary.
3. Set a 4 byte nonce in bytes 39..42
4. Hash the data with `cn_slow_hash`, you'll get 32 bytes back, that's your hash. Note, this result hash is binary - it's a 32 byte number. If you want to *display* it, you need to convert it to a hex string.
5. Compare the result hash against the next block difficulty (again, converted to binary). The calculation to see if your hash meets the difficulty is as follows:

   - *b / h* (where *b* is the *base* difficulty, *2^256-1*, and *h* is your result *hash*)
   - If the result is greater than or equal to the next block difficulty (as returned from `get_block_template` at step 1), you've mined a block and can submit it to the network using the RPC call [submit_block](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#submit_block).
   - If it's not, repeat from step 3 with a new nonce.

Doing this all in Python is pretty straightforward because Python supports big numbers, but, it will be terribly slow.

I've omitted specifically how to call `cn_slow_hash` as the [README](https://github.com/ph4r05/py-cryptonight/blob/master/README.md) already shows how trivial it is to call.

Comment: Hi, How could you do this? I'm not super experienced but I'll try.

Comment: Also, would cryptonight version would this be(for example, cryptonight v8, cryptonight heavy, etc)

Comment: More specifically, how do you add the 4 byte nonce in bytes 39..42?

Comment: "How could you do this?" <- If I give any more guidance I'll be writing it for you!
"Also, would cryptonight version would this be" <- The question was for Monero, so CryptoNight v2.
"how do you add the 4 byte nonce" <- change bytes 39..42 to any random values.