# Can someone show me how to hash with CryptoNight in Python?

Tags: mining-theory

I need a Python(2 or 3) Monero miner that outputs hashes to terminal.

Please ask me if you need clarification.

Comment: Could this work, with some modifications? Also, I forgot where I found this so if it looks familiar to you, please link me to it. import socket import json import hashlib import binascii from pprint import pprint import time import random import os import binascii import pycryptonight import struct address = '' #Enter pool info here password = '' nonce = hex(random.randint(0,2**32-1))[2:].zfill(8) host = '' port = 0000 print("address:{} nonce:{}".format(address,nonce)) print("host:{} port:{}".format(host,port)) sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) sock.connect((host,port))

Comment: If I can only hash with cryptonightv2, what coins can i mine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a follow-up question to your [previous question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10830/im-trying-to-create-a-python-miner-can-i-get-some-guidance-please).

Here is an example that shows how to hash a block hashing blob with a supplied nonce:

```
import binascii
import pycryptonight
import struct

bhb = binascii.unhexlify("070786a498d705f8dc58791266179087907a2ff4cd883615216749b97d2f12173171c725a6f84a00000000fc751ea4a94c2f840751eaa36138eee66dda15ef554e7d6594395827994e31da10")
nonce = 1234
bin = struct.pack('39B', *bytearray(bhb[:39]))
bin += struct.pack('I', nonce)
bin += struct.pack('{}B'.format(len(bhb)-43), *bytearray(bhb[43:]))
hash = pycryptonight.cn_slow_hash(bin, 2)
print(binascii.hexlify(hash))
```

Where `bhb` is the binary of a `blockhashing_blob` as returned from a call to [get_block_template](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block_template), and `nonce` is your nonce for this particular hash.

To create a miner, follow the steps in [my answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/10832/7493) to your other question.

Comment: I get an error when I run this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "miner.py", line 7, in <module>
    bin = struct.pack('38c', *bhb[:38])
struct.error: char format requires a bytes object of length 1

Comment: Written and tested for Python 2. You are trying in Python 3.x

Comment: Whilst this isn't a Python support SE, I have updated so it will work in Python 2 & 3 now.

Comment: Ok, so I got it to work. Thanks! but, it when it outputs to the terminal, it has a 'b'  in front of the cryptonight hash. b'547951be7d8843bbf48ef6f69b59380f9b5225e2b6a3aa115ea16e53439ee0d4'

Comment: And also, do hashes hashed change based on the bhb?

Comment: Also, Is it possible to get the bhb from online? i dont want to run the monero daemon. Like, for example, a pool? or idk,

Comment: Also, doesn't the nonce have to go up every time you hash? like it starts at 0000 then after a hash it goes up to 0001?

Comment: "it has a 'b' in front" <- You can `.decode()` the string you are printing (or just run with Python 2). E.g. `print(binascii.hexlify(hash).decode())`. "do hashes hashed change based on the bhb" <- Of course. If bhb changes, the result of hashing it will of course change also. "Is it possible to get the bhb from online?" <- Of course. Call the `get_block_tempate` RPC call on any public remote node.

Comment: Where online???

Comment: node.moneroworld.com:18089/json_rpc

Comment: also, what about the nonce?

Comment: What about the nonce?

Comment: Like, does it have to go up every time it hashes?

Comment: Yes. A miner would use a new nonce each time till it finds a valid hash. This was already outlined in https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/10832/7493

Comment: Lets move this over to the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89298/discussion-between-crypthusiast-and-jtgrassie).

Comment: How could I get the bhb from somewhere else than the wallet ? I don't want to run the wallet. I want it from an online source. Like a block explorer. Anyway. Does it get it from the pool.

Comment: You don't get it from a "wallet". You get it from either a call to the daemons RPC as already detailed or from a pool.