# How can I generate the blockhashing blob for my Python miner?

Tags: mining-theory

I am in the works of making a pool-compatable fully python miner, and I need to know how to generate the blockhashing blob for the miner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1 in [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/10832/7493) details how to get a `blockhashing_blob`.

If you plan on creating it yourself instead, this is much more involved. You would have to deserialize the `blocktemplate_blob`, calculate the merkle tree root hash for the blocks transactions (including a newly constructed coinbase transaction), then concatenate the block header, merkle tree root hash and transaction count (as a varint). That would get you a manually constructed `blockhashing_blob`. Doing this in just Python will be a big task.

It's worth noting, a pool-compatible miner doesn't need to create a hashing blob as the pool gives the miner the blob to hash.